# installing codeigniter sparks manager on windows

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter, curl, command-line-interface

**SOLVED, read bottom of post:**

I'm trying to install the Sparks package manager on windows by following the [official instructions](http://getsparks.org/install).
Issuing this command:

```
php -r "$(curl -fsSL http://getsparks.org/go-sparks)"
```

results in this errormessage:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in Command line code on line 1

If I only execute the curl command within the above line, i.e this:

```
curl -fsSL http://getsparks.org/go-sparks
```

it echoes out the php script located on the URL. So I think the problem is piping the curl output to PHP somehow fails. I've tried a couple of variants, using diffrent quotes etc but I'm at a loss.

**MY SOLUTION**
As DaveRandom pointed out, the instruction didn't apply to windows.

But instead of doing it the manual(normal) way, what I did was taking the output from curl, appending php script tags and executing it as a file with the php -f option.

Here is the output:

```
<?php
$zip    = "http://getsparks.org/static/install/spark-manager-0.0.7.zip";
$loader = "http://getsparks.org/static/install/MY_Loader.php.txt";

if(!file_exists("application/core"))
{
    echo "Can't find application/core. Currently this script only works with the default instance of Reactor. You may need to try a manual installation..\n";
    exit;
}

echo "Pulling down spark manager from $zip ...\n";
copy($zip, "sparks.zip");

echo "Pulling down Loader class core extension from $loader ...\n";
copy($loader, "application/core/MY_Loader.php");

echo "Extracting zip package ...\n";
if(class_exists('ZipArchive'))
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('sparks.zip') === TRUE)
    {
        $zip->extractTo('./tools');
        $zip->close();
    } else {
        echo "Extraction failed .. exiting.\n";
        exit;
    }
} elseif(!!@`unzip`) {
    `unzip sparks.zip -d ./tools`;
} else
{
    echo "It seems you have no PHP zip library or `unzip` in your path. Use the manual installation.\n";
    exit;
}

echo "Cleaning up ...\n";
@unlink('sparks.zip');

echo "Spark Manager has been installed successfully!\n";
echo "Try: `php tools/spark help`\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you linked do explicitly state;

> In order to use this quick start option, you should be using OSX or some flavor of linux.

You need to follow the `Normal Installation` instructions for use on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the command `php -r "$(curl -fsSL http://getsparks.org/go-sparks)"` in your root application folder. Maybe you're executing this command at wrong folder.